# How to access the serialized data in PHP file in the following scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, serialization

How to access the serialized data in a PHP file in following situation?
The code and the serialized data is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(document).on('click', '#delete_url', function (e) {    
e.preventDefault();

var items = new Array();
$("input:checked:not(#ckbCheckAll)").each(function() {
  items.push($(this).val());
});

var str = $("#user_filter").serialize();    


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "manage_users.php?op=delete_bulk_users&items="+items,
  data: str,
  dataType: 'json',  
  success: function(data) {
    //var message       = data.success_message;            
    var redirect_link = data.href;
    alert(redirect_link);
      window.location.href = redirect_link;
  }          
});
```

});
    });

The data I'm getting in after serialize in `str` is as follows:

```
op=group_filter&page=1&from_date=11%2F10%2F2000&social_login=&to_date=11%2F10%2F2013&login_criteria=all&user_name=&user_state=&user_email_id=&user_city=
```

Now the PHP file(manage_users.php) is as follows:

```
/*The code is actually one of the switch casees*/
prepare_request();
  $request = empty( $_GET ) ? $_POST : $_GET ;
$op         = $request['op'];
switch( $op ) {
case "delete_bulk_users":
print_r($request);/*For printing the received array of values after form submission
                    Here I'm not getting serialized data */
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you serializing, what are you sending it to?

Comment: Maybe this script can be useful http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/javascript-url-querystring-get/

Comment: You realise that you're serializing a string right? And that's what happens when you serialize a string?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: from jQuery doc on `serialize` - The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard `URL-encoded notation.` that is why you are getting that html encoded value. what are you trying to acheive with that `str`??

Comment: @tymeJV:I want to use send this data through ajax request to PHP file. But for that I've to send the data in proper format. So I'm asking for help in converting the data into proper format or any other trick which will give correct data.

Comment: this is the proper format, did you try and see what data you are getting in the server side??

Answer (score 0):

The `serialize` function is intended to be used to create a query string for a URL from a collection of inputs (or an entire form), and will out of necessity encode characters such as `/` (which denotes a directory in a URL). There's no way to tell `.serialize()` to convert to the "proper" format because *it already is*.

If you're using the result of `.serialize()` as part of an AJAX request it's fine to do that like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourpage.php',
    data: str, // the string returned by calling .serialize()
    ... // other options go here
}).done(function(response) {
    // do something with the response
});
```

Your server should handle decoding those characters when it receives the request and provide the correct values to you.

If you're using it for something else you could try using the native JavaScript [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function to convert those encoded characters back, like so:

```
str = decodeURIComponent(str);
```

Note that calling `decodeURIComponent` and then trying to use it for an AJAX request **won't** work.

For more information on URI encoding take a read through the MDN entry for [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: :Thanks for your help. But tell me how should I send the proper data to PHP file through $ajax() method?

Comment: @PHPGeek Edited the answer to include that. You just pass your encoded string from `.serialize()` as the value for the `data` option when calling `$.ajax()`.

Comment: :Actually I'm not able to get the values in PHP file. Can you help me in it? For this I can modify the question and show you the comoplete code. Should I modify my question?

Comment: @PHPGeek I'm not overly familiar with PHP having never coded in it, but I can generally work out parts of it. Go ahead and edit the code into the question, if I can't figure it out there may be somebody else who can.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Give me five minutes to modify the question.

Comment: :I've modified my question.

Comment: @PHPGeek Hm, what's the value of `$op` when that code reaches the switch statement? I'd expect it to be `group_filter`.

Comment: I'm getting [op] => delete_bulk_users . The value I'm sending alongwith URL

Comment: @PHPGeek Ah, I missed that, I was looking at the value in the example output from `serialize()`. That makes sense. Which value are you having the issues retrieving server-side then? Can you edit in the output from `print_r($request);`?

Comment: :I'm having issue in accessing the serialized data contained in str variable.